# None of the IE versions load my font files

Tags: css, internet-explorer, font-face

I have put below font face in my CSS.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'sfnt';
src: url('../sfnt.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
src: url('../sfnt.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
url('../sfnt.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
url('../sfnt.ttf') format('truetype'); /* Safari, Android, iOS */
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

If I try to open my web page in any of the version of IE it does not load my font files.
It works fine with Chrome, safari, Firefox.

I searched the similar questions logged in Stack Overflow and tried all the possible solution. Nothing seems to work.

Please let me know what is going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: What font did you use and where did u get it from? Is It a webfont?

Comment: @Jop Yes its a web font. I used [link](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/01/how-to-make-your-own-icon-webfont) to create my web font.

Comment: Where are the fonts located in relation to the directory your CSS file (or HTML if this is inline) resides

Comment: Have you checked to see if the directories that the page is trying to load them from match the folder structure based on that page?

Comment: @Deryck All my fonts are placed in the root directory where the index.html is present.

Comment: Ok so does that mean the fonts are in the same directory as this file that you're showing us

Comment: @Andy Holmes Event If I remove the dots (../) and put only the file name the result is same. Font files and index.html is in the same root folder.

Comment: @RohitPai can you post a screen shot of folder structure? Also, have you tried directly accessing them online to see if the path is correct/file exists?

Comment: You might not have access to the files through your server.  If you uploaded them and (assuming apache) httpd doesn't have read access you'll have to chmod to adjust

Comment: @Rohit Pal tried using just one dot in front of the / ?

Comment: @jCuber Yes I tried, no difference.

Comment: I got it working in IE 9 and above, I just disabled compatibility view. Now its problem only with IE8.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to access the url of the .eot font directly i.e http:///sfnt.eot what happens?

Comment: This isn't an answer, it is a comment

Comment: I only had 48 reputation. I couldn't make it a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Google Fonts, It's better to compatibility and you can use google cdn. If you can't find your font, you may try to use the syntax of then.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Wellfleet';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Wellfleet'), local('Wellfleet-Regular'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/wellfleet/v1/qu15OBOh_Q0T8ooRUaKSDT8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff) format('woff');
}
```

The Google Fonts API is compatible with the following browsers:

```
    Google Chrome: version 4.249.4+
    Mozilla Firefox: version: 3.5+
    Apple Safari: version 3.1+
    Opera: version 10.5+
    Microsoft Internet Explorer: version 6+
```

via https://developers.google.com/fonts/faq